# Installing mono messed something on my computer

Tags: ubuntu, apt, mono

How can I fix this issue:

```
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: mono-roslyn (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but 5.18.0.240+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Recommends: referenceassemblies-pcl but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: msbuild but it is not going to be installed
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.5.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 (>= 1.4.8~) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-mono mono-roslyn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mono-roslyn
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates-mono
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
149 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5 600 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 312351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mono-roslyn_5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mono-roslyn (5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-roslyn_5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/csc', which is also in package chicken-bin 4.13.0-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mono-roslyn_5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$
```

I tried to install mono by

```
jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https dirmngr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dirmngr is already the newest version (2.2.12-1ubuntu3).
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (1.8.0).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: mono-roslyn (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but 5.18.0.240+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
              Recommends: referenceassemblies-pcl but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: msbuild but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.7lPVGXOSvM/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
gpg: key A6A19B38D3D831EF: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key A6A19B38D3D831EF: "Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-vs.list
deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic main
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                                                
Hit:6 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
27 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: mono-roslyn (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but it is not installed
              Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.18.1.3-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) but 5.18.0.240+dfsg-2ubuntu2 is installed
              Recommends: referenceassemblies-pcl but it is not installed
              Recommends: msbuild but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
(base) jaakko@jaakko-GL553VW:~/Desktop/Programming$
```

Comment: How did you install mono? Have you done `apt-get update` and tried again? Could you remove mono and install it using `apt-get` after running `apt-get update`?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how to improve your questions and increase the probability of getting helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` already tells you what you should try next:

> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

If that fails for some reason, or doesn't fix your issue, please update the question with the output of that command.